# How to remove initial (on the left) "+" or "0" from a telephone number string?

Tags: php, regex, string, ereg-replace

I need a regular expression in PHP to remove from a string of telephone numbers the + or the 0 at the beginning of a number.

I have this function to remove every not-number characters

```
ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $sPhoneNumber)
```

but I need something better, all these examples should be...

```
$sPhoneNumber = "+3999999999999"
$sPhoneNumber = "003999999999999"
$sPhoneNumber = "3999999999999"
$sPhoneNumber = "39 99999999999"
$sPhoneNumber = "+ 39 999 99999999"
$sPhoneNumber = "0039 99999999999"
```

... like this

```
$sPhoneNumber = "3999999999999"
```

any suggestions, thank you very much!

Comment: You want "003999999999999" to become "3999999999999"? What if the number legitimately start with 0?

Comment: @mbratch that would not work. for example take this number: "909984302", your expression would result in "9998432"

Comment: @mbratch that would still result in the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~^[0\D]++|\D++~', '', $sPhoneNumber);
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to regular expressions, you can use [`ltrim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php):

```
echo ltrim('003999999999999', '+0');
```

The second parameter is a character list string, in your case `+` and `0`.

**Note:** This will not remove whitespace within the string, only the `+` and `0` from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Just `intval()` afterwards to remove leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

For removing the beginning `+` or `0`, this should work

`ereg_replace('^(\+|0)+?', '', $sPhoneNumber);`

Answer (score 0):

Just extend your expression by a few alternative cases:

```
ereg_replace("^\+|^00|[^0-9]", "", $sPhoneNumber)
```

See http://ideone.com/fzj16b

Comment: that's not working on "039 99999999999", you setted only an exactly number of zero (one), i want it generic

Comment: @axel Just add more cases, or work with `^0+` instead of `^00`. I merely showed you the direction.

Comment: i understand it @Tomalak, but i can't add undefinitely zeros, i don't know clients how many zeroes can add, i've to prevent mistakes.

Comment: @axel But `^0+` *means* an undefinite number of zeros.

Comment: that's true ;), sorry i'm not addicted to regex

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you don't need regex at all. Here is a clean solution as well.

```
// first remove spaces
// trim + and 0 characters at the beginning
ltrim(str_replace(' ', '', $sPhoneNumber), '+0');
```

this is my test code

```
<?php
$sPhoneNumber[0] = "+3999999999999";
$sPhoneNumber[1] = "003999999999999";
$sPhoneNumber[2] = "3999999999999";
$sPhoneNumber[3] = "39 99999999999";
$sPhoneNumber[4] = "+ 39 999 99999999";
$sPhoneNumber[5] = "0039 99999999999";

foreach ($sPhoneNumber as $number) {
    $outcome = ltrim(str_replace(' ', '', $number), '+0');
    echo $number . ':' . "\t" . $outcome . '(' . ($outcome === '3999999999999' ? 'true' : 'false') . ')' . "\n";
}
```